# How to use {totalPages} in paginatorTemplate?

Tags: jquery, css, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to achieve following :-

[image]

following is my Datatable code :-

```
<p:dataTable id="datatableid" 
        var="record"
        value="#{myController.records}" 
        selectionMode="single"
        selection="#{myController.selectedRecord}"
        rows="10"
        paginator="true"
        currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord} - {endRecord} of {totalRecords} Records Displayed, {totalPages}"
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  &lt;span class='pg-text'&gt; Pg &lt;/span&gt; {JumpToPageDropdown} {totalPages} {RowsPerPageDropdown} "
        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
        scrollable="true" 
        paginatorPosition="bottom"
        >
```

I want to use {totalPages} in paginatorTemplate.

**Question : How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found following solution :-

```
<p:dataTable id="datatableid" 
    var="record"
    widgetVar="mydtwidget"
    value="#{myController.records}" 
    selectionMode="single"
    selection="#{myController.selectedRecord}"
    rows="10"
    paginator="true"
    currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord} - {endRecord} of {totalRecords} Records Displayed, {totalPages}"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  &lt;span class='pg-text'&gt; Pg &lt;/span&gt; {JumpToPageDropdown} &lt;span class='pagecount-text'&gt;  &lt;/span&gt; {RowsPerPageDropdown} "
    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
    scrollable="true" 
    paginatorPosition="bottom"
    styleClass="my-datatable"
    >
```

I used jquery to get number of totalpages by using widgetvar of datatable.

Script after dataTable :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var pagecount = PF('mydtwidget').paginator.cfg.pageCount;
        $(".my-datatable .ui-paginator .pagecount-text").text(" of "+pagecount);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it with Jquery and using `widgetVar` to access `Paginator` object using `getPaginator()`.

```
<p:dataTable id="datatableid" widgetWar="myTableWidget"
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  &lt;span class='pg-text'&gt; Pg &lt;/span&gt; {JumpToPageDropdown} &lt;div class='pg-temp-total'&gt;  &lt;/div&gt; {RowsPerPageDropdown} "
             ...>
...
</p:dataTable>
```

Put this Script after Table

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.pg-temp-total').text(PF('myTableWidget').getPaginator().cfg.rowCount);
</script>
```

This is one solution that on top of my head right now, its an un usual way, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Any reason for down voting?